# How to get specific row, knowing the primary key value?

Tags: sql

This is probably very easy question for you sql gurus, but I never used sql before.

If the table "Person" has 3 rows : Name (primary key), Age and City, I know I can get all rows like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Person;
```

But if the table looks like this :

```
Name   Age   City
-------------------
A       2     NY
B       4     BE
C       6     PA
```

What sql command do I have to use to get (for example) the 2nd row? I know the Name is B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name = 'B';
```

This solves this particular problem, but you can visit [w3schools sql tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/) for the starting.

Comment: @taskinoor What if you don't know the field value?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT * FROM Person
 WHERE Name = 'B';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `SELECT * FROM Person WHERE Name='B'` more about select syntax you can find here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using primary keys that are related to any data in the entity. There is almost never a good pick. Primary keys should not change... Names can change (Both for cities and Persons) Also a SSN might "look" like a good candidate, but even they rotate over time, and you might happen to employ an illigal alien with a faked SSN Number ;)

So please allways use an integer that just counts up, or a guid.

Besides that, the answer has been posted several times already...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ask a question about each aspect of sql on here (you'll probably have quite a few), do a bit of reading first:

http://w3schools.com/sql

Comment: Actually I did, but the page I read didn't explain what I asked. Anyway, thanks for the link, I will use it as a reference.